# Requiring another file unsets all variables set before in a required file

Tags: php

I am currently writing some code that I am using to build a simple website. In the `main.php` file I require one file (`load.php`) which then requires two more files (`config.php` and `config2.php`). Now if I set in `config.php` the variable `$config["title"] = "Title";` and don't set it in the `config2.php` file, it gives me an error in the `main.php` that the `$config["title"]` is not set. This is a very simplified version of my code:

```php
<?php // main.php file
require load.php
echo $config["title"];
```

```php
<?php // load.php
require("config.php");
require("config2.php");
```

```php
<?php // config.php
$config["title"] = "Title";
$config["url"] = "example.com";
```

```php
<?php // config2.php
$config["url"] = "mydomain.org"/;
```

Now in the `main.php` file, it returns me an error that `$config["title"]` is not set. Any idea why? I am not searching for a function to unset all variables, my problem is that the second `require("config2.php);` unsets all variables from `require("config.php);` for no reason and I don't want that.

I have tried `require_once`, `include` and `include_once` in the hopes that I did something wrong there, but it appeared I did not.

However, when I removed the `require("config2.php");` it worked just fine (but it is not what I want to achieve, I want to require both files).

My ultimate goal is to require both files and have like a default config file that sets all default variables and a custom config file that the webmaster can edit which doesn't contain all variables.

Best regards.

Edit: I fixed it, the problem was that I accidentally put an `$config = [];` at the end of `config2.php` which lead that all the variables got unset. Thx to @Barmar

Comment: You have a syntax error in `config2.php`, the `/` before `;`. And `require load.php` should be `require "load.php";`. You're missing the quotes and the `;`.

Comment: Is that really the whole `config2.php`? My guess is you have `$config = [];` as well, which removes any old settings.

Comment: @Barmar the syntax errors don't mean a thing, they're not like this in the actual code.

Comment: And you were right, I hid at the end of the `config2.php` a `$config = [];` which lead to the variables after that to be unset. Thanks!

Comment: If you post code that isn't like the actual code, how do you expect us to figure out what the actual problem is? Luckily I've been at this a long time, so I've become a good guesser.